# Gradle build throwing error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have created a sample gradle project on intellij.

I go to the project root folder and execute the following:

```
./gradlew installDist
```

I am getting this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Task 'installDist' not found in root project 'HelloWorld'.
> - Try:
>     Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
>   BUILD FAILED

Please please let me know the resolution for this. I have spent one hour on this with no resolution.

Comment: Why do you think, you have the `installDist` task in your sample project? Exception says there is no such a task. Try to run `gradlew tasks` ti list all the task. Or if you suppose, it should be there, then post the whole script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to try a gradle with a sample project, the best way to do it - not to use any IDE at all.
First of all create a directory for your project and make it as a current directory by doing so

```
mkdir myapp
cd myapp
```

Then check if gradle is in your PATH by

```
gradle -v
```

You should see something like this

```
Gradle 2.12
```

Now you are ready to create your first gradle build script. You may do it in vim editor or what ever you want.

```
vim build.gradle
```

And just copy and paste following code in your build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

So you may try do build the empty project

```
gradle build
```

also you may want to add gradle wrapper

```
gradle wrapper
```

this command will add `gradlw` scripts and `gradle`directory with wrapper binaries.

So you are ready to add the java code to your project. You should create folders defined in java-project layout

```
mkdir src
mkdir src/main
mkdir src/main/java
mkdir src/test
mkdir src/test/java
```

As a result you will get

```
myapp  # project root folder
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java        
    └── test
        └── java
```

And then just import this project in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks Gordeev. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with springboot application.Then i saw there is no `install` dir under `build`.

Then add `id 'application'` to `build.gradle--plugs`, it worked well.

This problem shows we dont know `gradle` no doubt.